# CVS checkout by branch excluding removed files

Tags: cvs

Is it possible to execute `cvs checkout -r tag_name`, but exclude files in the attic? I would like to pull files with the given tag, but not files that have been deleted.

Pruning empty directories does not help, and I've run out of ideas after reading the CVS documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve the effect by doing a normal checkout with the files deleted then use `find` and `xargs` to do a `cvs update –r` on individual files to revert each one to your tag.

You'll want to exclude the cvs directories from `find` and check any new files added since the tag have been handled correctly.